# Ajax Call not returning successful but script executes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call made using a custom callback function invoked from Redactor.JS - The Ajax itsself posts data to a function which stores the information in a database. I know the POST is being made and the script executing because the information itsself is being stored correctly however the .success function of the ajax call is not completing and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

My call is in full below. 'data' is not logged in the console and I have attempted all manner of alerts etc

```
 $.ajax
            ({
                url:'<?php echo base_url('cms/page/'.$this->type.'/create/'.$this->page_id); ?>',
                type:'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:  'content=' + $('#redactor').redactor('get')+'&status=draft&title='+ $('#title').val() +'&sub=' + $('#sub').val()+'&id=<?php echo $this->page_id;?>&tags='+$('#tags').val()+'&dynamic_save=true&post_page=true',
                cache: false
            }).success(function ( data )
            {
                    console.log( data );
            });
```

Comment: Are sure what ur returning from ur php file..?? means check return datatype.?? And also check .error() its going for any error..??

Comment: ↑↑↑ Is your server side script returning JSON?

Comment: Hi my script is returning

     echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true', 'last_saved' => date('G:i', time()) ));

Comment: Get rid of the dataType property in the ajax call.  You should at least be able to view the response data then and see if there's anything that looks wrong.

Comment: Hi @Archer thanks for this - this has helped me immensely, I was outputting some content after my json data which has obviously caused the issue.

Comment: No worries - glad it helped.  When computer says it's wrong, it is wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to test this code which is working for me

```
var config = {
        url: YOUR_URL,
        type: 'post',
        data: {"key1" : "val1","key2" : "val2"},
//      headers: HEADERS(optional),
        dataType : 'json'
        success: function(data){
               console.log(data);
            // handle success response
        }
    };

$.ajax(config);
```

OR you can use .done method intead of .success see [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)